# Voltage oscillates continously in USB Li-ion charger. Anomaly or CC/CV behavior?

Tags: usb, battery-charging, constant-current, 5v

I have purchased two USB boards for charging Li-ion batteries and it should have a CC/CV charging regime. So I connected the board to a 5V USB source (computer first then solar panel) and the voltage at the output of the board reads values that oscillate around 3.5V. It is the same for both boards. The problem is that I am afraid to connect the battery when I have such an oscillation.

I was wondering if I am overreacting or is this a normal behavior for the voltage to vary in order to give a first CC regime? I only tested it with the multimeter and not on the battery itself. Maybe the Voltage would stabilize with a load, but I won't take the risk yet.

Can anyone help me to understand this and do the right safe thing?

Here is the USB charger with the voltage reading behind.

[image]

Comment: I think you are overreacting.  Figure out how to measure current or simply sense the temperature of the IC and battery with your finger. Then measure it. There is nothing you have reported that is alarming yet. Benign, nominal.

Comment: Thank you. I have now connected the battery and I'm reading the current using the multimeter. I get a small oscillation in current as well. I get 0.77A, 0.75A, 0.79A etc. And it changes every one second. Is a variation of 0.02A normal? If I charge the battery using a Step-Down Converter with Li-ion charging control, I get a constant current and that is what made me overreact, I guess.

Comment: Can you detect any temp rise? I guess that is a ~2h rate?   I haven't tested your board, but it seems fine

Comment: You should keep records of charge rate and time for your own experience.

Comment: I can only detect a temperature rise in the controller. It's relatively hot, which is what I would expect. Nothing on the battery side though. No strange behavior

Comment: 0.02A doesn't seem like a lot. It might be on purpose, as part of some kind of smart charging feature. Or it could be a shitty designed board, I guess.

Comment: It costs them about $1 to produce this card in high volume.  Give it more respect for a charger with no fan and heatsink and read the datasheets then give me your analytical theory why it responds this way and I'll send you 250 LEDs 20Cd 4500'k @ 20mA and 2kpcs if it is well done.

Comment: Why "then solar panel" enters this picture? Feed the board first with a known good voltage. Then, you purchased "two USB boards". How the heck we are supposed to debug unknown board's behavior? Again, which battery? Capacity?

Answer (score 1):

Given no technical information in the question, yes, a normal Li-Ion charger is supposed to turn its output voltage OFF when current drops below certain set point. Having no load certainly meet this condition (zero current). Then the charger needs to check if the battery is present or not, so it turn the power ON and checks for current. An so on. So yes, a no-load charger will do this periodically, aka "oscillates".